# How to set different environment variables for each managed host in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i have an inventory file which looks like below.

```
[abc]
dsad1.jkas.com
dsad2.jkas.com
[def]
dsad3.jkas.com
dsad4.jkas.com
[main:children]
abc
def
[main:vars]
ansible_user="{{lookup('env', 'uid')}}
ansible_password="{{lookup('env', 'pwd')}}
ansible_connection=paramkio


main.yaml --> main yaml looks like below

---
- hosts: "{{my-hosts}}"
  roles:
  - role: dep-main
    tags:
    - main
  - role: dep-test
    tags:
    -test

cat roles/dep-main/tasks/main.yaml
- name: run playbook
  script: path/scripts/dep-main.sh
```

where i have scripts folder inside which i have dep-main.sh --> using script module to run the shell script  on remote machine.

```
 "ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "my_hosts=main" --tags main main.yaml"
```

i am following above design for a new requirement. Now the challenge is i need to set environment variable for each host and env variables are diff for each host. how can i achieve it . please help me.

there are around 15 env key value pairs that needs to be exported to each host above, out of which 10 are common, where i'll simply put in the above shell script. where as other 5 env key value pairs are diff for each host like below.

```
     dsad1.jkas.com
        sys=abc1
        cap=rty2
        jam=yup4
        pak=hyd4
         jum=563

      
dsad2.jkas.com
 sys=abc45
 cap=hju
 jam=upy
 pak=upsc
 jum=y78
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the ansible documentation for this as it's rather explanatory:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

I am editing my initial answer and try to make it more clear. But please note that I am assuming a few things here:

1. you are using Linux
2. you use bash as your shell, Linux offers a variety of shells and the syntax is different
3. when you say export environment variables I assume you mean copy the variables to the remote host in some form and export them to the shell

Also there's a few things left to do but I have to leave it to you:

- You need to "load" the env file so the variables are available to the shell (export), you can add an extra line to the ".bashrc" file to source the file, like "source /etc/env_variables", but that will depend on how you want to use the vars. You can easily do that with your shell script or with ansible (lineinfile)
- I recommend you use a separate file like I did and don't edit the bashrc adding all the variables. It will make you life easier in the future if you want to update the variables.
- Rename the env file properly so you know what's for and add some backup mechanism - check the documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html

Inventory file with the variables:

```
all:
  hosts:
    <your_host_name1>:
      sys: abc1
      cap: rty2
      jam: yup4
      pak: hyd4
      jum: 563
    <your_host_name2>:
      sys: abc45
      cap: hju
      jam: upy
      pak: upsc
      jum: y78
```

My very simplistic playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:

    -  name: Create env file and add variables
       blockinfile:
         path: /etc/env_variables
         create: yes
         block: |
           export sys={{ sys }}
           export cap={{ cap }}
           export jam={{ jam }}
           export pak={{ pak }}
           export jum={{ jum }}
```

The final result on the servers I used for testing is the following:

```
server1:
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
export sys=abc1
export cap=rty2
export jam=yup4
export pak=hyd4
export jum=563
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK

server2:
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
export sys=abc45
export cap=hju
export jam=upy
export pak=upsc
export jum=y78
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Hope this is what you are asking for.
For windows you may have to find where the user variables are set and adjust the playbook to edit that file, if they are in a text file...

Comment: Thanks for the response  but i wanted to export above key value pairs as an environment variables on remote hosts. if i do echo ${sys} on remote system --> it should give abc1

Comment: Need help on how can i use them in the role/tasks/main.yaml file, so that they'll get exported to the remote server according to hostname like dsad1.jkas.com

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand your question, what do you mean by "exporting to the remote server"?
You use the variables as any other ansible variable with {{ var_name }}, when you run the playbook against the inventory file ansible will replace the variable accordingly, for instance the value for "sys" in the server dsad2.jkas.com will be replaced by abc45, you just just the var as in {{ sys }}.

Comment: sorrr, if my above msg is not clear enough,  i want to set hostvars defined in the inventory file as environment variables on remote machines. Where these host vars are diff for each host.

Comment: ` [abc]
dsad1.jkas.com sys=abc1,cap=rty2
dsad2.jkas.com sys=abc45,cap=hju `

Comment: Above i kept two host vars next to dsad1.jkas.com. So i want these two vars available on the host dsad1.jkas.com as an environment variable. So that i can use them on that remote host.